# How to import .flt files into GRASS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, import

I am trying to import a raster file (.flt) into GRASS. The raster file (.flt) was generated from HEC-RAS. The said raster format cannot be imported into GRASS (it shows the error "file not supported"). Is there a way to import the .flt into GRASS?

Comment: I tried using r.in.bin but I can't convert my coordinates to the required format

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `r.in.gdal` will be able to import *.flt files. I just browsed some posts in GRASS Mailing lists, though the last one reports errors while importing due to some reasons, you could try them.

1. [[GRASSLIST:3013] arcview](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/GRASSLIST-3013-arcview-td1850468.html)
2. [Floating Grid to raster GRASS](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Floating-Grid-to-raster-GRASS-td5567473.html)
3. [Error in r.in.gdal](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Error-in-r-in-gdal-CPLCalloc-Out-of-memory-allocating-for-quot-EHdr-ESRI-hdr-Labelled-quot-driver-td1877571.html#a1877572)

Comment: Thanks. I visited the links you posted but it does not discuss the error I am experiencing for loading .flt files. The "file not supported" error occurs whenever I tried importing .flt files in GRASS

Comment: @teamAngat, not a good suggestion, but still have you tried posting the question on GRASS User's mailing list?

Comment: yes, I already posted it but it is still pending. What I am currently doing in order to import the *.flt file into GRASS is to use arcgis (temporarily) to convert the file. The arcgis that we are currently using is only a trial version. We cannot use arcgis since the software that we are using has no budget, so we should only use open source software.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to convert to a raster format GRASS prefers?