# How can GRASS export an .flt file?

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I am using GRASS and connecting it to another application. The other application needs an FLT file of the raster map which I should export from GRASS. The other application only reads FLT files. Can GRASS export an FLT file

Comment: Related import question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11606/import-raster-flt-into-grass

Comment: Isn't the [GRASS manual](http://grass.fbk.eu/gdp/html_grass64/r.out.bin.html) of any help?  After all, .flt (ESRI float export) files are just a [string of single-precision binary values](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~jwo/landserf/landserf230/doc/howto/fileformats.html#arcGridFloat) plus a header file.

Answer (score 1):

If FLT is supported by GDAL, then just use r.out.gdal and select that format.